# Dropbox authentication with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, dropbox, dropbox-api

my problem is that when I'm trying to get access_token from Dropbox, with my Phonegap application, I get the following error:

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/www/index.html#access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}&token_type=bearer&state=%3CCSRF+token%3E&uid=130101032

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyLoginDropbox, false);
    function onDeviceReadyLoginDropbox() {
         var url = document.URL, 
        shortUrl=url.substring(0,url.lastIndexOf("/"));

    console.log(cordova.InAppBrowser);

    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/authorize?client_id={APP_KEY}&response_type=token&redirect_uri='+shortUrl+'/index.html&state=%3CCSRF%20token%3E', "_blank");
    }
```

So, everything works fine, but the redirect isn't so, what is the workaround here? I read that with JS you are not able to access to local files, so how I am able to get access token then when redirect isn't working? Only possiblity is  to use JS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle redirect event from cordova.InAppBrowser.

You can add him event handler on page load.

You have to check login success (you can search "ACCESS_TOKEN" in url),
and take it from the success url.

Code it's like this:

```
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
       // you have here url at event.url

       if(event.url.indexOf('success') > -1){
         // take token


       }

 });
```

You can find all events [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html).